# Is there an example from Classical antiquity of mixing up cities based on their names?

Tags: ancient-history, names, cities

Is there an example from Classical antiquity of mixing up cities based on their names? Say, an army landed at the wrong town, or a traveler gave wrong directions, *based on the names*. That last part is what I'm looking for, so this excludes the Greeks' landing at Mysia thinking it's Troy.

My question is motivated by curiosity. There were, after all, several Alexandrias, and in Egypt there were three Hermopoleis. That there were two Thebes, and had to be described by the number of their gates, was legendary since Homeric times. Does anyone, in history or myth, ever get confused by this?

Comment: Live at those times would have been extremely local (yes, I know, there were long distance merchants and sailors, but still). So very few people in Greece would have any link to Thebes in Egypt (even during Ptolomain era), so context would have been enough of a clue for practical purposes.

Comment: @SJuan76 I'm not so sure. Besides soldiers and merchants, you had diplomats, itinerant teachers, well-traveled historians, and mail deliverers. Seemingly any one of those could have confused things. You also have 3 Hermopoleis in Egypt alone, so you could have mix up even in local travel.